# Angular: Error when creating object in service from Javascript class

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, oop

Using angular, I have a javascript file `src/assets/readData.js` with a single class inside.

```js
class Configs {
  constructor() {
    this.Config = "";
    this.branches = this.readBranches();
    this.setBranch();
    // ....
  }

  // ....
}
```

And I have a Service src/data.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

declare var Configs: any;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
  configs: any;

  constructor() { 
    this.configs = new Configs;
  }
}
```

I am trying to create an object from the javascript class inside `data.service.ts` `this.configs = new Configs;`. I read that I can just put `declare var Configs: any;` at the top of the service file (which I did). However when loading up my webpage, I get the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'Configs' has already been declared (at readData.js:1:1)`

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I was also including the readData.js in my index.html file. I removed it from there and the error is resolved.